# Find strings with spaces in command prompt

Tags: string, windows, command-line, find

Using the command `net user %username% /DOMIN` and I am trying to cut the results to make the output smaller, however when I use `| Find "text here"` I am only able to search for one string with spaces per command. Is there a way to `| Find` with multiple strings that contain spaces?

Example: `| Find "User name"` `| Find "Full Name"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saying that `| Find "User name" | Find "Full Name"` does not work?

Unfortunately [`find`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725655) does not work with multiple strings. But [`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459) does.

```
...| Findstr /i /L /c:"User name" /c:"Full Name"
```

should work for you.

...oh, I see! You want `string1` **or** `string2` but cascaded `find` will filter for `string1` **and** `sting2`...

Comment: I can run the entire "net user" command to get each result on a new line, but I want to do it all from one run only if possible.

Comment: As I said, `find` does not work with multiple strings. findstr does. Therefore, to find lines that contain either one string **or** another, you need to use `findstr`, as demonstrated.

Comment: So is it possible to run the command 1 time, and output multiple strings with spaces in them? I tried but I dont think Im doing it right.

Comment: Have you tried `net user %username% /DOMAIN|Findstr /i /L /c:"User name" /c:"Full Name"` ? What was the result? What was the output of the `net user %username% /DOMAIN` command that produced the result? What result did you expect? I can't test because my setup doesn't produce any lines containing either string `User name` or `Full name`.

Comment: net user %username% /DOMAIN   -- gives you a bunch of stuff about the account like, name, user id, password last set, etc etc. And when I would use the Find command, it would pull only the lines from it that I specified. But what you just posted above works with multiple strings.

Comment: That's very helpful! I used this for ipconfig to pull out different things. IPConfig /All>C:\Junk.txt &  FINDSTR /i /L /c:"DNS" /c:"DHCP Enabled" /c:"Description" C:\junk.txt  & echo "DNS today"